# SimpleXml not gives proper output

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am using Soap for web service call and PHP for entire operation.When i send request i get the response as "341025COMPLETE". But when i select it for Source it prints the xml behind it.

XMl is something like this :

```
"<testscreening xmlns="https://www.test.com/xml/services/PSI">
<response>
<reportID>341025</reportID>
<backgroundreport></backgroundreport>
<status>COMPLETE</status>
</response>
</testscreening>"
```

If i want its output that i can store into database how can i can achieve it ? 
Note : xmlns mentioned here is change as per the privacy.

Comment: "xmlns mentioned here is change as per the privacy" A good idea, but please use example.com or example.org as these domains are registered for that purpose only.

Comment: SOAP != SimpleXML. You are talking about loading a document with SOAP but didn't tell us where SimpleXML gets involved. What is your problem/question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DOMDocument`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$el = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach($el as $one){
    if($one->nodeName == 'reportID'){
        $reportId = $one->nodeValue;
    }
    if($one->nodeName == 'status'){
        $status = $one->nodeValue;
    }
}

echo $reportId.' - '.$status;
// 341025 - COMPLETE
```

Comment: One could also use `DOMDocument::load()` to directly load the XML contents from some file, e.g. a SOAP response.